# Redirecting sub-directories from http to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have just re-directed my site from http to https using the following htaccess rewrite rule

My website is in a folder under public_html.Let's say the folder name is "mySitefolderName"

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.mysite\.com\/mySitefolderName\/" [R=301,L]
```

With this rule , I have achieved redirecting my site from http to https,
but old links on google to sub-directories under "mySitefolderName" are not being redirected

for example let's say I have this old link on google : 
    mysite.com\mySitefolderName\someSitePage.php

If I follow this link from google it still continues with http

How should I make sure that all old links to sub-directories are also redirected to https ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this rule in `/mySitefolderName/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add https    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=302,L]

# add www    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thank You for the help.
When I add this,my site is not loading.
I get an error that my site has an redirect loop

Comment: But it did change the old urls. The old links on google were changed to https.

Comment: No I did not have the htaccess file at all in "mySitefolderName".

Comment: I had "RewriteOptions inherit" in my public_html's htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Anubhava. After removing "Rewrite Options inherit" from the public_html's htaccess and adding your code in mySitefolderName's htaccess it is working now.But I have one more problem. The old links are redirected from http to https but since they don't have "www" prefix , I am getting a certificate warning before proceeding to https. Could you please modify the above rule such that "www" prefix is also added to the old links

Comment: Even if you add an extra rule to add www cert warning will still come because cert negotiation happens before running rewrite rules.

Comment: As you said it still gives the warning. Is there any other way that all old links to my website on google are updated to https and also   with www prefix so that I don't get the warning.

Comment: Could you also point me to few links where I can learn about these rules ? And thanks again for your expert help.

Comment: You can use http://askapache.com It has some very good tutorials on `mod_rewrite`.